# SSH client timeout or max tries

Tags: ssh

i write a script to ssh to a server in a loop using public key. However, because of some reason my public key was not correctly copied to the login server. So, i will be hanged at servers with fault public key. the situation can be exampled like below:

- i use **eval `/usr/local/bin/ssh-attach`** on my desktop to record the passphrase corresponging to private file A when login to the remote servers
- however, serverA have added A.pub corresponding to private key file A to authorized_keys file
- i have a private key file B on my desktop, so when trying to ssh login serverA it will hang with a prompt to ask passphrase.

Does ssh have some params to config to bypass this situation?

Comment: so the problem is forcing ssh to use a specific private key?

Comment: @xlembouras  if you do specific a private key, it will be ok. However, i wander if ssh have some params to let this situation login fail and the command return a non-zero value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-i` option to specify the key you want the ssh to use.

`ssh -i path/to/key/file user@example.com`

or you can add the equivalent setting to your ssh config file

```
Host Example
  User john
  IdentityFile /path/to/file
```